# Change host from Amazon for S3 and set it to work with Ceph radosgw

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, radosgw

Is that possible, to change system from Amazon S3 to work with the other S3 provider, like cap radosgw? I'm using league/fly system-aws-s3-v3 and aws/aws-SDK-PHP packages for Laravel, but they want me to type the region, which I don't have on Ceph radosgw, and automatically connect me with Amazon services. I was trying to add my server as an 'endpoint' in filesystems.php, but it is still forcing me to choose a region.
This is my s3 disk configuration:

```
's3' => [
    'driver' => 's3',
    'key' => 'XXXTXOXXXFXX77XXXXXX',
    'secret' => 'XXXX2XXXXXXS85XXXX5XXXXXXXXRXXXXXXX4XXX',
    'bucket' => 'my-bucket',
    'endpoint'  => 'http://s3.mysite.io'
    ],
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

> Missing required client configuration options: region: (string) A "region" configuration value is required for the "s3" service (e.g., "us-west-2"). A list of available public regions and endpoints can be found at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html.

Comment: Take a look at this issue on `flysystem`, it appears you can do this natively: https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/issues/662

Comment: blame Taylor Otwell, it's a Laravel error, not a flysystem one https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-aws-s3-v3/issues/131